# creating dataTables from pug mixin with DOM datasource keeps saying "No data available in table"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables, pug

I made a jade mixin to create a table from values I'm passing from node. I am instantiating dataTables at document ready but I keep getting "No data available in table"

I have a feeling that there is a race condition between the two that is leading to the issue.

here is pug

```
            table#brandPageTable.table.table-bordered.table-hover(name="Brands")
          thead
            tr
              th Company Name
              th Industry
              th Contact Name
              th Contact email
              th Contact Phone Number
          tbody
          mixin liveCampaigns(brandID,name,type,contactName,contactEmail,contactPhoneNumber)
            tr.clickable-row(data-url='/superUser/brands/'+brandID)
              td=name
              td=type
              td=contactName
              td=contactPhoneNumber

          for brand in brands
            +liveCampaigns(brand.id,brand.clientName,brand.businessType,brand.contactFirstName,brand.contactEmail,brand.contactPhoneNumber)
```

and here is the js

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $('#BrandsTable').DataTable();
  });
```

Comment: Questions must include a minimum viable example of your code and a description of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that runs into this problem the issue was the tbody tag. For whatever reason the pug was creating two tbody tags and the dataTable would take the first body which always happened to be empty